# System.IO Cannot create file with valid Paths?

Tags: c#, winforms

Lets get straight to it,
Here's my code:

```
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        if (!File.Exists(@"./Application/logs/" + today.ToString("d").Replace("/", ".") + ".txt"))
        {
            File.Create(@"./Application/logs/" + today.ToString("d").Replace("/", ".") + ".txt");
        }
```

For some reason its giving me this error.

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\**REDACTED**\source\repos\Application\Application\bin\Debug\Application\logs\10.4.2021.txt'.'

I ran through some tests and went to its directory, The directory is there.

Thinking #1: I think its adding a dot at the end, if that's true can you find a way to prevent it?
Thinking #2: It might be thinking this as a directory.

Comment: Your use of `File.Create` is a bit weird anyway, since you're ignoring the [`Stream` that it returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=net-5.0) (thereby leaving it open, meaning that you will be locking the file when you try to do anything else with it). At a guess, the subfolder Application or Application\Logs doesn't exist.

Comment: `C:\Users*USER*` is not a windows special directory to start with

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm guessing that should be `c:\Users\**REDACTED**\source` :)

Comment: The directory is there.

Comment: Despite that, can you humour me and add `Directory.CreateDirectory("./Application/logs/")` before the `File.Create` line?

Comment: Debug your app and check the path (suggestion: calculate the path once and use a variable in the two places you use it).

Comment: It's not adding a `dot` to the end of your path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One or more of the directories you've specified doesn't exist, that's why it's throwing a `DirectoryNotFoundException`.

Try creating the directories first, prior to creating the file.

```
var today = DateTime.Now;
var path = Path.Combine( @".\Application\logs", $"{today.ToString( "d" ).Replace( "/", "." )}.txt" );

var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName( path )!;

// You don't need to check if the directory exists first.
Directory.CreateDirectory( directory );

if ( !File.Exists( path ) )
{
    using var file = File.Create( path );    
    // Do some awesome stuff with your newly created file.             
}
```